# Fix ftp connection issues on 000webhost.com hosting

Tags: web-hosting, ftp

I set up WordPress site at 000webhost(dot)com as pre-step to figure things out before paying for domain and hosting. It was fine for few days.

Problem is that i can't seem to find **reliable way to connect via ftp to get my site files up/downloaded**

What i want to achieve

- access my files on the server reliably (compare local vs live files, delete temps, etc..)
- work on my site locally (not change things in life version)
- sync between live and local versions
- have a local backup

For first few days i could've connected via ftp or their file manager without problem.

Since then I am getting connection time out. Apparently after few days you gotta use VPN to be able to connect !?

However even with VPN I'm getting constantly disconnected and can't get all files to e.g. compare with my local files. I'm getting following errors.

```
Error listing directory '/public_html'.
Could not retrieve directory listing
Illegal PORT command more:
```

```
Could not retrieve directory listing
MLSD: Connection timed out
```

Each time i change VPN location. Errors rate gets "lower" but withing ~10 minutes and longer i stay connected, more frequent errors become until i get permanently disconnected from the server again.
Then i have to change VPN location to even be able to connect.
It can't even finish comparing / downloading 170 MB of files (WP site).

000webhost says they are blocked by many ISPs due to hosting tons of shady services. They recommend using VPN.

My WP webpage is alive and working well. I can access WP admin panel. I can log in to 000webhost dashpanel with no issue. I'm connected via fibber optics, never had issue with that. I haven't reached traffic quota yet: ~10 %

I tried:

- log in via their file manager: it's quite limited, also not working without VPN.
- Filezilla / WebSCP:

  - transfer mode passive etc according [000webhost blog](https://www.000webhost.com/blog/wordpress-ftp)
  - = errors increasing overtime as described above.
- Firewall allowed everything for ftp clients / disabled FW = no effect
- verify ftp status on their discord bot = online running

How to make connection stable / reliable to sync my local and live site?

Comment: Have you contacted their tech support?  They would be able to look at logs

Comment: FTP is a horrible (and old and insecure) protocol. The problem may well be that it requires 2 connections - the difference between active and passive FTP is which side initiates the second one.  I would try an active mode connection if passive fails.    Looking at their website it looks like their $3/month plan and upwards support SSH access.  You may want to check with them that that plan also supports SFTP and SCP (which I expect they would), change to that plan and use SFTP or SCP - both of which run on top of SSH and are simpler and more secure to use.

Comment: Another possibility - which kind of defeats the point if you are after "cheap" which the hosting you are getting implies - is to get a VPN with a static IP address.   Most VPN's are designed for privacy, so NAT and sharing the IP address is a feature.  A VPN with a static IP address means there won't be the 1:MANY port mapping issue and will likely allow you to use FTP.   That said, between paying for a VPN with a static IP and FTP and paying for SSH, SSH is a no brainer.

Comment: @Steve Well their support is community forum.

Comment: @davidgo 
I wanted to figure out website making before making commitment to pay $/m for a 12-24months.  
I know FTP is horrible and outdated. They even require plain ftp which is insecure as hell but there is no other option with 000webhost AFAIK.  I hate that but i though about it being temporary until i figure if this the way to go. 
So I can't use alternative. 
I planned to go with their pay-plan on Hostinger in near future but now I'm understandably reluctant.

Comment: If you eant to figure out web making at no cost, have you considered running a webserver on your PC?   EG - https://blog.containerize.com/how-to-install-and-configure-wamp-server-on-windows/ ?

Comment: @davidgo i set up clone site on local pc  but I need site to be online as well.  I ended up setting up site in google cloud VM. So far it works better. I'm not excepting millions of visitors so it might also be better alternative budged vice after free credits run out than paying for hosting.